# Select both the start and end time of a SoundCloud track

Tags: soundcloud

I notice that appending `#t={minutes}:{seconds}` to a SoundCloud URL will start a track at a specific point.

Is it possible to also define a stop time on a track?

Example: https://soundcloud.com/stack-exchange/stack-exchange-podcast-51#t=9:36

Comment: Why would use "email" as a tag on this question? This might be useful: [What are tags, and how should I use them?](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/tagging)